# Connect to Postgresql in Entity Framework with the name of the team

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, ip

I need to establish a connection with postgresql using the name of the team and not the ip, currently I do it by entering the ip or localhost, now I need to do it with the name of the team, but when entering the name of the team does not allow me because there is no configuration in the pg_hba file

App.config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" 
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conexion" 
         connectionString="server=192.168.1.3;user id=postgres;password=contraseña;database=nombre" 
         providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

App.config, I try to do this: replace ip with the computer name (server)

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" 
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conexion" 
         connectionString="server=NAME_PC;user id=postgres;password=contraseña;database=nombre" 
         providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

File pg_hba

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: DNS needs to be able to resolve NAME_PC to the actual ip address of the server that postgres is running on, it should not have to be in pg_hba

Comment: if it resolves but not as an ip: PostgresException: 28000: no hay una l�nea en pg_hba.conf para �fe80::a1d6:694f:74cc:981b%13�, usuario �postgres�, base de datos �template1�, SSL inactivo

Comment: thanks to solve it, add in IPv6 local connections: IPv6 local connections: host all all :: 0/0 md5